# How can I select a specific set of tests (not in same package) to run in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Using Run Configurations you can specify groups of tests to run, provided that they are in the same class or the same package.  However, I want to specify a group of tests, where the tests are sprinkled throughout my test suite.

I was not able to find specific instructions for how to do this.  I figured out a way, and thought I would share it here, in case anyone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an annotation (can be applied to a test class or to a test method), and having the test runner filter on that annotation.

#### Define Test Annotation

```
/**
 * This annotation is used to mark tests for devices with a physical
 * keyboard (Chromebook).
 *  
 * The annotation can be applied to test classes, and to individual
 * tests.
 */
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PhysicalKeyboardTest {
}
```

#### Use Test Annotation

```
@Test
@PhysicalKeyboardTest
public void enterKey_shouldWork() {
    ...
}
```

#### Run Configuration - Single Device

In the Run Configuration dialog, under "Android Instrumented Tests"

- Make a copy of "All Android Tests" configuration
- Rename copy to "Physical Keyboard Tests"
- In "Instrumentation arguments"

  - Name field: annotation
  - Value field: com.*path-to-annotation-def*.PhysicalKeyboardTest

The "Physical Keyboard Tests" run configuration will run all tests annotated with "@PhysicalKeyboardTest", anywhere in the test suite.

#### Run Configuration - All Connected Devices

In the Run Configuration dialog, under "Gradle"

- Add a configuration:

  - Name: Physical Keyboard Tests (all devices)
  - Gradle project: *select your app*
  - Tasks: connectedCheck
  - Arguments: -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.annotation=com.*path-to-your-annotation-def*.PhysicalKeyboardTest

The "Physical Keyboard Tests (all devices)" run configuration will run all tests annotated with "@PhysicalKeyboardTest", anywhere in the test suite, on all of the connected devices.